# bot not connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch

```
var settings = {
channels : ["#channelname"],
server : "irc.twitch.tv",
port: 6667,
secure: false,
nick : "myBot",
password : "oauth:numbers"
}

var irc = require("irc");

var bot = new irc.Client(settings.server, settings.nick, {
channels: [settings.channels + " " + settings.password],
debug: false,
password: settings.password,
username: settings.nick
});


bot.say(settings.channels, "I'm here!");

console.log("Connected");
```

This worked yesterday for me, but now it does not show the bot is even in the channel.

In command line I start the script with node scriptname.js and it says "Connected".

Is my config wrong?

Sometimes it connects, others it doesn't. Here are the bot values for when it's running:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the connection is happening asynchronously and you're not actually waiting for a connection to occur. It will print "Connected" immediately, but you never actually connected or waited for a connection to happen yet. `bot.say` will not do anything until you're actually connected!

The proper way to detect if you're connected is to do something like this:

```
bot.on('registered', function(message) {
  console.log("Connected");

  bot.say(settings.channels, "I'm here!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it doesn't solve the problem. It just doesn't connect, I've tried multiple twitch accounts. Does it matter where the directory for the irc is? I moved it from %appdata% to documents and changed the directory to where I moved it

Comment: It's possible that you have permissions issues but if you're simply not able to connect then your config must be wrong (outdated oauth, wrong port, etc.)

Comment: I tried everything, I don't get it. My port is right. It works now, I have no idea what happened...

Comment: Alright, my computer froze when I tried to run the bot (100% memory/disk usage) and when I restarted my computer it stopped working again.. (6 GB of RAM)

Comment: How would I debug this?

Comment: Why are you doing `settings.channels + " " + settings.password`? `settings.channels` is an Array, not a string, so if you have more than one value, it'll mess up.

Comment: To debug it, do `bot.on('error', function(e) { stuff })`. If an IRC error occurs, it'll say something.

Comment: Because you're able to connect to multiple IRC servers at once. It's in the docs http://node-irc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API.html. Also it worked like that regardless, now it doesn't with nothing in the settings changed. I get nothing logged from the error event when this happens.

Comment: `Array + String === String` in JS. The API takes an array with channels. If you have more than one channel, that will not work correctly.

As for the bugginess, I don't know what specifically is the issue is if no errors are being thrown. Assuming that the program does not close immediately and doesn't print errors, it should remain connected. My hunch is that either something with the authentication is breaking on occasion or a general issue with their server.

Perhaps setting `debug` to true will result in some useful error being thrown, but I can't guarantee it; `node-irc` is quite buggy.

Comment: I fixed the issue, I believe it was a DNS error. It could not resolve irc.twitch.tv. I inputted the IP of one of the IRC servers from twitch and it works every time without any fails so far.